# Passing an array of structures to an Oracle stored procedure (CFMX)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, coldfusion, associative-array

I'm looking to write a Oracle stored procedure where I would pass in (from ColdFusion) an array of structures and loop over each iteration to insert the bits and pieces within the structures to the DB.,

I haven't written this type of procedure / package before.  I am planning to do an sp / package similar to what is sketched out in the second reply to this thread: [How to pass a array of object to oracle stored procedure](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1078772)

Assuming I do, how can I call the procedure from ColdFusion (I'm using MX) and pass in my array?  As far as I can see, none of the CF_SQL_Types make sense.

Comment: CF -> SQL Server via XML makes sense, not sure if it's viable for Oracle.  Yes, none of the CF_SQL_Types will make any sense.  If this is critical to you, you can build it in Java and let CF invoke the Java method responsible for calling the store procedure I guess.

Comment: cfsqltype="cf_sql_longvarchar" works for XML passed as a string, not as a CF XML type. This also works for Oracle.

Comment: You can pass arrays using Java ([see answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33160309/1509264)) and if you combine it with the [code snippet here](http://www.justskins.com/forums/stored-procedures-jdbc-116480.html) then it should be do-able in ColdFusion - however I've yet to work out how to use ColdFusion's data sources or whether it is possible to use any of the built in functions to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have passed arrays of any data type to an Oracle SP is to use the OCI interface and collections.  If there is a way to do it in straight Pro*C I have not found it.

OCI is a more 'verbose' interface.  Here is a the base documentation.

http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10779/oci11oty.htm#421737

Comment: [Internet Archive link here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090820020421/http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10779/oci11oty.htm) - however the linked page is for C and appears to have nothing to do with ColdFusion.

Comment: Yes.  That is what Pro*C is.  C.  To my knowledge you cannot pass arrays as described in the question, using coldFusion.  ColdFusion does support an OCI interface - C calls I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array of structs, I'd recommend just converting the data to XML and passing that to Oracle.