# Comma Seperated Query for Multiple Parametes in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am able to query comma separated IN parameter in PLSQL so far with reference to [Query with comma seperated IN parameters in PLSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126779/query-with-comma-seperated-in-parameters-in-plsql/33126961?noredirect=1#comment54112363_33126961).   and working perfect. My question how do I implement this same solution for at least 3 comma separated parameters. My query parameters are like this,

```
I_PRODUCT query (R%, L%)
I_MODEL query (E%,T%,R%)
I_TYPE query (A5,B%,C%)
```

Is it good to make as a function and call for all these parameters? Any other quick solution?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RQUERY1
(
 I_PRODUCT VARCHAR2
 I_MODEL VARCHAR2
 I_TYPE VARCHAR2
, O_Cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR

) AS BEGIN
O_Cursor := NULL;

OPEN O_Cursor FOR
WITH PROD_SEARCH AS
(
     select regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT,'[^,]+', 1, level) pattern from dual
     connect by regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
)
SELECT * FROM table1
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM PROD_SEARCH WHERE table1.PRODUCT LIKE pattern );
END RQUERY1 ;
```

update: I am looking to query the parameters (I_PRODUCT,I_MODEL,I_TYPE) from my java code using stored procedure and need to display the output value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

I finally understood what you want.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654494/can-we-have-multiple-with-as-in-single-sql-oracle-sql), you can define multiple with statements. So you can write it like this:

```
OPEN O_Cursor FOR
WITH PROD_SEARCH AS
(
     select regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT,'[^,]+', 1, level) pattern from dual
     connect by regexp_substr(I_PRODUCT, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
),
MODEL_SEARCH AS
(
     select regexp_substr(I_MODEL,'[^,]+', 1, level) pattern from dual
     connect by regexp_substr(I_MODEL, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
),
TYPE_SEARCH AS
(
     select regexp_substr(I_TYPE,'[^,]+', 1, level) pattern from dual
     connect by regexp_substr(I_TYPE, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
)
SELECT * FROM table1
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM PROD_SEARCH WHERE table1.PRODUCT LIKE pattern )
AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM MODEL_SEARCH WHERE table1.MODEL LIKE pattern );
AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM TYPE_SEARCH WHERE table1.TYPE LIKE pattern );
END RQUERY1 ;
```

Comment: Updated my question like below:I am looking to query the parameters (I_PRODUCT,I_MODEL,I_TYPE) from my java code using stored procedure and need to display the output value.

Comment: @KodS I *think* that I understood what you want. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I exactly looking for

Answer (score 2):

Use a collection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RQUERY1
(
 I_PRODUCT IN  SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST,
 I_MODEL   IN  SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST,
 I_TYPE    IN  SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST,
 O_Cursor  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN O_Cursor FOR
  SELECT t.*
  FROM   table1 t
         INNER JOIN TABLE( I_PRODUCT ) p ON t.PRODUCT = p.COLUMN_VALUE
         INNER JOIN TABLE( I_MODEL   ) m ON t.MODEL   = m.COLUMN_VALUE
         INNER JOIN TABLE( I_TYPE    ) y ON t.TYPE    = y.COLUMN_VALUE;
END RQUERY1;
/
```

Then you can call it in Java like this:

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;
import oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleTypes;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor; 

public class TestDatabase {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@url:port:sid","UserName","Password");

            String[] products = { "Product1", "Product2", "Product3" };
            String[] models   = { "Model1", "Model2", "Model3" };
            String[] types    = { "Type1", "Type2", "Type3" };

            ArrayDescriptor des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST", con);

            CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall("call TEST.RQUERY1(?,?,?,?)");

            st.setArray( 1, new ARRAY( des, con, products ) );
            st.setArray( 2, new ARRAY( des, con, models ) );
            st.setArray( 3, new ARRAY( des, con, types ) );
            st.registerOutParameter( 4, OracleTypes.CURSOR );
            st.execute();
            ResultSet cursor = ((OracleCallableStatement)st).getCursor(4);

            while ( cursor.next() )
            {
                int id = cursor.getInt(1);
                String product = cursor.getString(2);
                String model   = cursor.getString(3);
                String type    = cursor.getString(4);

                System.out.println( String.format( "Id: %5d", id ) );
                System.out.println( String.format( "  Product: %s\t", product ) );
                System.out.println( String.format( "  Model:   %s", model ) );
                System.out.println( String.format( "  Type:    %s", type ) );
            }
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```